# Netbeans Error: "Could not add one or more tag libraries"

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 6.1 and Tomcat 6.0.1.6.

I made some very minor changes to a project that had been working and now I am getting the following error:

com.sun.rave.web.ui.appbase.ApplicationException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Could not add one or more tag libraries.

The only change I made was to a backing bean method, no new UI components, jsp, etc.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Are there any nested exceptions or a cause-exception?

Answer (score 1):

I get the idea that Netbeans regenerated/updated the web.xml or sun-web.xml files in your project. Perhaps someone made some changes to one of those files that were overridden when Netbeans updates those files.

To prove it, revert your changes and see if the error still occurs. If so, backup those files, make your code changes, rebuild or whatever and then copy those backed up files over the Netbeans modified files and build.